# pulling multiple modules to fulfill a total criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I currently have a INDEX+MATCH solution in place that I use to pull out matching criterias.. here is the current setup that I work with :-

Have an excel with two sheets, - Data sheet contains an inventory master of sorts where.. we can see each item being displayed with multiple batches in with each of their own quantities depending on where they're stored.. - Sheet 1 is an order form in which my end user would like to get the exact batch of a product on the basis of two criterias.. Criterias being - product number and qty match to fullfill..

Formula being used - `=INDEX(C:R,MATCH(1,(C:C=W3)*(R:R>=Y3)*(D:D>=X3),0),3)`

Data - Current Inventory

```
Item Quantity Batch
ABD  10       11223a
ABD  15       24589r
DFG  5        T45678
DFG  67       ghytu8
FGH  10       thnh67
FGH  10       huip78

Sheet 1 - Order form
Item  Quantity  Batch
ABD   8         
DFG   4
DFG   10 
FGH   10
```

New requirement:-

As seen above we have multiple batches for a certain product, now currently if the order quantity is higher than whats available within a single stock module.. The report does not pickup the combination of batches to fulfill the request. Could you please advise on what sort of a function I could use in excel where if the order quantity is higher than that of a single inventory module. It should allocate stocks from that module till its limit and then find the next available module. Please see below example of how the new output should look.

Data - Current Inventory

```
Item Quantity Batch
ABD  10       11223a
ABD  15       24589r
DFG  5        T45678
DFG  67       ghytu8
FGH  10       thnh67
FGH  10       huip78

Sheet 1 - Order form
Item  Quantity  Batch   Quantity picked from Batch
ABD   18        11223a  10    
                24589r  8 
DFG   6         T45678  5 
                ghytu8  1
FGH   15        thnh67  10
                huip78  5
```

Can this be resolved with help of any sort advanced excel function/query ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to use a proper database or write a routine to do this in VBA.

Comment: The data you see in the 1st table is actually extracted from an AS400 database via the excel ODBC driver. Would it still be possible to write a VBA routine that could help in the above mentioned case ?